# Session cookies working on all subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, cookies, subdomain

i have my site set up like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/profile.php?name=%1 [L]
```

what this does is if user visits: `test.example.com`, it will show contents of folder: `example.com/user/profile.php?name=test`. if someone goes to `lol.example.com`, it will show page: `example.com/user/profile.php?name=lol`

---

**Question 1:**

right now, I have a problem with it. if i go to `test.example.com/login`, it will show my domain root file. how can i make it so that it will show things from /user folder? for example: `test.example.com/login` will show `example.com/user/login` and `test.example.com/register` will show `example.com/user/register`?

**Question 2: SOLVED**

right now if i log in on the subdomain, the session cookie (PHP) is only set for the subdomain. how can i make the cookies work for the whole site with (example.com) domain?

thanks

UPDATE: for example: `test.example.com/pathtofile` should get the contents of `example.com/user/pathtofile`. "pathtofile" should be dynamic. i just want the path to look in the folder /user, not the root folder.

Comment: Not sure about htaccess question, but for the second question you need to set the domain to *.example.com.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php]
`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '*.example.com');`

Comment: I got the cookies thing figured out, had to clear history, cache, cookies, etc....

Comment: Is it not `$1`?

Comment: @LFlare can u please give me the code? dont know what youre saying, thanks

Comment: @baileyJchoi Not really sure here but can you try `RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/profile.php?name=$1 [L]`

Comment: @LFlare no sorry, that does not even take me to the page anymore, 404 eror

Comment: @baileyJchoi Ok, hang on, let me start an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/profile.php?name=%1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /user/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but its not only pages login and register. for example: `test.example.com/pathtofile` should get the contents of `example.com/user/pathtofile`. "pathtofile" should be dynamic. i just want the path to look in the folder /user, not the root folder.

Comment: @baileyJchoi Try this one. It should fit all your needs.